# how to configure the application context to get the spring bean in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have the maven struts2 spring hibernate integration project. I imported to the eclipse and run correctly. But when I reconfigured that project step by step by adding the predefined dependency to that project. It can't get the spring bean object from the application context file. 
So it throw the null pointer Exception. So how to configure to get spring object.

Comment: Show us the project structure how you have defined.

Answer (score 1):

**Note : Don't foget to add Listener in `web.xml`**

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

**Alternative 1 :** Use Spring's `WebApplicationContext`  In your Action in execute method

```
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

Public class yourAction extends ActionSupport{
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(ServletActionContext.getServletContext());
        UserBo userBo1 = (UserBo)context.getBean("userBo");
    }
}
```

**Alternative 2 :** You can specify DI in `applicationContext.xml`

```
<bean id="userBo" class="yourPackageName.UserBoImpl" />

<bean id="userSpringAction" class="yourPackageName.UserSpringAction">
    <property name="userBo" ref="userBo" /> 
</bean>
```

in `struts.xml`

```
//struts.xml
<action name="userSpringAction" class="userSpringAction" >
    <result name="success">pages/user.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In your action

```
public class yourAction extends ActionSupport{
    //DI via Spring
    UserBo userBo;
}
```

**Alternative 3 :** You can use Struts Naive Dependency Injection

**Step 1 :** In your `struts.xml`

```
<struts>
    <bean class="yourPackageName.UserBoImpl" name="userBo" />
    <package name="mydefault" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    ....
    </package>
</struts>
```

**Step 2:** In your action

```
Public class yourAction extends ActionSupport{

    // struts DI
    @Inject("userBo")
    private UserBO userBO;

}
```